# Low Pass filter with a resistor

Tags: low-pass

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTzSVZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hello i am learning about filters and make this circuit in many circuit simulators.
When i increase the R2 resistance the voltage across is increased and when i decrease it is decreased as well.
Shouldn't the voltage be the same always,since the R2 is in parallel.Or i have understand wrong the series and parallel connections?

Comment: R2 is loading your low pass filter, therefore changing the filter's characteristics.  R2 is in parallel with C1.  That combination is in series with R1.

Comment: Rule of thumb is to choose R2 >> R1 such as 10x R1 at a minimum but consider the attenuation and rise in output impedance.

Answer (score 1):

If for a moment, you remove C1 from the circuit you are left with two resistors in series, which when you measure the voltage across R2, it is a voltage divider.

The voltage over R2 will be 
\begin{equation} 
V_{R2} = V1 * \frac{R2}{(R1+R2)}
\end{equation} , so increasing R2 will increase the voltage drop across R2.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yeah but since they are in parallel isn't the voltage supposed to be the same that's what's bugging me

Answer (score 1):

The following schematic is a little bit more general-purpose than yours and covers a wider array of situations.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0Ee02.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For one thing, notice that I've added \$R_\text{S}\$ for the source impedance. In your schematic, that impedance is missing (assumed to be zero Ohms, I guess.) But all sources have some amount of impedance and your filter will load down that source. You have to be aware of this fact, if for no other reason than to discard its relevance based on an informed choice. Always keep in mind that there may be an important effect due to source-loading.

For another thing, notice that I've added \$R_\text{L}\$ (instead of your \$R_2\$) in order to highlight the fact that \$R_\text{L}\$ itself loads down the filter.

Put another way, a filter accepts a source, filters that source, and delivers the result to a load. But a filter -- most especially a passive, unpowered filter -- both loads down its source and is also loaded down by its load. So the filter doesn't exist in a vacuum. It exists as ***part*** of a system.

A very simple system may use an ideal source with zero source impedance. If so, you can assume that your filter doesn't load down the source. It may also use an infinite load impedance (effectively, an open circuit for its load.) And in that case, you can assume that your filter itself is NOT loaded down by the load (which doesn't present a load as its impedance is infinite.) Then, and only then, can you just focus on the filter and ignore what's driving it and what it is, itself, driving.

While you are using an ideal source with zero source impedance, you've taken to seriously loading down the filter. So of course you get different results with different load resistors.

Another way to look at it is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDwOSt.png)</sup>

Here you can see that \$R_\text{L}\$ very much impacts the output. If you made it zero Ohms, obviously the output would be grounded and therefore always zero-out. (The right side above provides a slightly more simplified view. But equivalent, just the same.) So the load resistance definitely impacts the filter output. It must, as you can readily see above.